# Is Spring more suitable for business-logic-focused apps?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control, autowired, ioc-container

After reading the official doc of Spring, I got this impression:

"Spring, specifically its IoC container, suits better for apps that requires only one instance of most classes".

For example we have an online shopping app. Its business logic is divided into

- Order process
- Payment process

and encapsulating these two parts into classes is for better code organisation rather than for implementing any functionalities, and Spring makes it easier to inject the same instance to whichever object needs it, to avoid frequent and redundant `new`.

However, in a Mario-like game, we might have a class `Coin` that requires hundreds of individual instances, and hence Spring can't be applied in this case ('cause I think `@qualifier` makes more mess than the good part brought by IoC).

Is the above correct?

Comment: No it isn't. An `OrderProcess` also has unlimited number of orders. A mario game also has an engine for which you can use Spring. The fact that you use Spring doesn't mean you need it for **everything**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in thinking that you wouldn't inject an object that only applies in a narrow scope.

I could see objects with `Request` scope that are not `Singleton`.  Spring has supported that from the beginning.

Method scope variables should not be under Spring's control.  There's nothing wrong with calling new.

You should understand Spring better before you make judgements about its efficacy.